# Python 3 архитектура и оптимизация работы с БД

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

Вопрос из серии стратегических.

Пишу достаточно объемную программу, но столкнулся с такой проблемой, что программа постепенно превращается в кашу, все больше косяков вылезает из неожиданных мест.

Суть: есть база данных на SQLite, с ней работают 5 функций по очереди. Одна из таблиц выгружается в массив. С остальными таблицами эпизодическая работа.

```
massive = [[1,2,3 ...], [1,2,3 ...]]

def func1():
    for element in massive:
        ...

def func2():
    for element in massive:
        ...
```

Массив применяется для того, что бы не тормозить работу постоянным применением commit().
Проблема возникает тогда, когда одна функция вносит изменение в таблицы (элемент массива), и другая далее работает с этими данными. В данном случае используется замена элемента, что бы последующая функция уже учитывала изменения.

```
element[0] = 1
```

Но, когда требуется внести изменения в разных функциях к другой таблицы, которая не выгружена в основной массив, приходится создавать точечные словари (ведь commit() используется только один раз в конце), что бы учитывать все изменения.

```
dict = {}

dict[id, value] = [1,2]
```

Собственно вопрос: как лучше реализовать объемную работу с БД с множеством операций над таблицами, не нагружая программу commit().

Сам я рассматриваю варианты: 1) создать словари по всем таблицам, а все функции объединить в одну. 2) ООП (в классе указывать все данныеи далее манипулировать ими), аля управление спрайтами ;)

Comment: Мне кажеться здесь лучше использовать SQLAlchemy . В ней есть возможность изменять объект глобально, без commit.

Comment: Если БД может быть выгружена в память, может, вообще поменять стратегию? Зачем куча обвязок СУБД для того, что может быть обработано прогой непосредственно...